# Deleting and adding entities asynchronously room. Can this introduce the following issues?

Tags: android, android-room

If I run an asynchronous call to delete all entities in room database and then add entities in a different asynchronous call, will there be a possibility of deleting the newly added entities?

These two calls will be run near the same block of code. Will entities being deleted potentially delete the newly added entities?

Should I avoid this by making callbacks upon completion of the initial delete task?

Comment: In general, I think that making a "callbacks upon completion of the initial delete task" would be a good design. Relying on implementation details of some particular async task executor that happen to be available on platform you happen to write code on would be, in general, a bad design.

Answer (score 0):

> By default, all queries (@Query) must be executed on a thread other than the main thread. (You work on that later.) For operations such as inserting or deleting, if you use the provided convenience annotations, Room takes care of thread management for you.

**Source:** [14.1A: Working with Architecture Components: Room, LiveData, ViewModel](https://google-developer-training.github.io/android-developer-advanced-course-practicals/unit-6-working-with-architecture-components/lesson-14-room,-livedata,-viewmodel/14-1-a-room-livedata-viewmodel/14-1-a-room-livedata-viewmodel.html#task3intro)

Comment: So if my queries are all run by executing an extension of a new AsyncTask<> and all of these are executed right after one another--line by line--the manager will chain these operations after one another? Or will this make a new thread for each of these tasks and, therefore, not necessarily execute in this intended order (I need to first delete then add new entities).

Comment: It seems "the manager will chain these operations after one another" should be true. I think you can first delete and then add new entities in the same thread. Even you can do both of them in a transaction to be able to rollback data if something bad happens.